# Not Able to reschedule apex batch class

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

enter code hereCurrently I have a batch which I'm scheduling after 2-2 minutes but because it has the same job name it doesn't allow to reschedule. Is there any way to reschedule the same batch. Because when i go to **All schedule job** in UI I can see it listed with no next schedule run. Now If i give different name it will run but with all the schedule batch listed in **All schedule job** . Please suggest me how to reschedule the same batch by apex.

```
String day = string.valueOf(system.now().day());
    String month = string.valueOf(system.now().month());
    String year = string.valueOf(system.now().year());
    String minute = string.valueOf(system.now().minute() + 2);
    String hour = string.valueOf(system.now().hour());
    String nextFireTime = '0 ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ?' + ' ' + year;
    BatchSample b = new BatchSample(); 
    CronTrigger[] jobList = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType,NextFireTime 
                                  FROM CronTrigger Where CronJobDetail.Name Like 'BatchSample' AND NextFireTime > :System.now()];
    if(jobList.size()==0)
        System.schedule('BatchSample', nextFireTime, b);
```

Comment: Could you please share the cron expression you're using?

Comment: @blank updated the question with code

Comment: This seems like a very [XY-ish](http://xyproblem.info) design to me. Why not use batch or queueable chaining? Why schedule a batch class two minutes in the future with the same constant name? Why not use `System.scheduleBatch()` with the `minutesFromNow` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

While scheduling the Job you can put different name all jobs like append current Datetime:

I have put example for this:

```
Datetime sysTime = System.now().addSeconds( 120 );

String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();

System.schedule( job.getJobName() + sysTime, chronExpression, (System.Schedulable)job );
```

you can put different name in first parameter of `System.schedule`

Comment: Yes If i put different name it will schedule, But I want the same scheduled Apex to get reschedule is that possible ?

Comment: Well it will actually be the same Apex. Just the different job name. If you want to reschedule exactly the same job, you have to wait until the previous one finishes.

Comment: @RaviKant, Are you reschedule your batch when first batch is finished or some other way?

Comment: @ChandraKiran yes I'm trying to give the new date time to the scheduled apex but it says 'The job name is already scheduled for execution' . Also I'm scheduling in the finish method

Comment: @blank until and unless I don't delete it from 'Schedule job' page it doesn't allow me to create batch with same name even though the batch has been processed.

Comment: @RaviKant can you please show the code. so that we can identify how you are scheduling? because I have check we can schedule same batch class with different name

Comment: @ChandraKiran I have shared the code in the question please have a look, Yes we can schedule same batch class with different name , but my question is to reschedule same batch scheduled using the same job name

Comment: if any job is running with same name you have to abort that first that schedule new one.